# pass a list as arguments to ggplot

Tags: r

I would like to pass a list as arguments to ggplot. The solutions I found so far usually use do(), but I don't know how to use that here. In the example below I would like ggplot to take the name and limits argument from the variable.

```
library(ggplot2)
p<-ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) + 
  geom_point()

p

yscale<-list(limits=c(0,40), name='A Y scale name')
p<-p+scale_y_continuous(yscale) #how to change this line?
p
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `do.call`:

```
yscale<-list(limits=c(0,40), name='A Y scale name')
p <- p + 
  do.call(scale_y_continuous, yscale)
```

Comment: ugh, silly me, for some reason I thought I can't call scale_y_continuous on its own ... thanks